# Specific problem with Implementation of a Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

*Java*

I am attempting to write a merge sort algorithm in order to sort a list of custom objects into alphabetical order, I have now been looking at my code and the pseudocode for a couple hours and have yet to figure out why it isn't working,

Perhaps some fresh eyes could help,

My code is as follows...

```
    /**
     * Merge Sort Algorithm
     * @param array array to sort
     * @param i - point to start sorting at
     * @param j - point to end sorting at
     */
    public void MergeSort(Movie[] array, int i, int j) {

        if(i < j){
            int m = (i+j)/2;

            MergeSort(array, i, m);
            MergeSort(array, m+1, j);

            merge(array,m);
        }
    }


    void merge(Movie[] array, int m){
        int p = 0;
        int q = m+1;
        int r = 0;
        int j = array.length-1;

        Movie[] temp = new Movie[array.length];

        while(p <= m && q <= j){
            if(array[p].compareTo(array[q]) == 1){
                temp[r++] = array[p++];
            }else{
                temp[r++] = array[q++];
            }
        }

        while (p <= m){
            temp[r++] = array[p++];
        }
        while (q <= j){
            temp[r++] = array[q++];
        }
        System.arraycopy(temp,0,array,0,temp.length);
    }
```

When testing on cases of "a,b,c,d,e,h,y,z", the output is as follows...

```
a |
b |
d |
e | 
h |
c |
y |
z |
```

Evidently this is not in alphabetical order, just can't figure out why

Comment: You need to implement `Comparator<Movie>` to compare `Movie` classes - `compareTo` you're using fails to accomplish this comparison.

Comment: The compareTo function used there, is a self built override function, to sort alphabetically, it works

Comment: It's helpful to see your entire `Movie` class implementation, as if the Comparator is not implemented properly there might be the problem. Please post your entire code so it will be more insightful.

Comment: I'm wary of posting my entire code, as this work is for a university assignment, I can vouch for my comparison to be working as I have copied another implementation of merge sort and it works flawlessly using my comparison. I do however, need to get my implementation working.

Comment: I think your merge implementation is not correct. When you call merge, you have to merge from the start to the end, in your case: from i to j

Comment: A function `merge` is supposed to merge two parts. Your version has only two parameters: `array` and `m`. If you think about it; how can it implement the `merging` given those two parameters?

Comment: The pseudocode I am working off
https://pasteboard.co/J6TvKnf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the pseudocode you've posted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604036/specific-problem-with-implementation-of-a-merge-sort-algorithm#comment108971738_61604036) I can tell you that you haven't implemented that given pseudocode.

The *Merge(A[i...j], m)* function has the parameters *m*, which is the mid, the array *A* **and** the parameters *i* and *j* to define the bounds for the merging in that array. In my opinion the pseudocode is just not precise and bad.

The parameters *i* and *j* are used to initialize *p* and *r*. In your current implementation you are initializing both with `0`, which is not what the pseudocode does.

Your method `merge` needs those two parameters `i` and `j` to define the bounds for the merging.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll see if I can implement it without breaking anything

Comment: Atm, I'm just getting IndexOutOfBounds and NullPointers left right and center